# Easiest way to have just 2 networks for a small guest house

Tags: networking

I have a very small guest house. I want to allow guests to watch Netflix on hard wired smart TV's I am scared that if the TV's are on my home network then they will have access to my computer and personal info.

What is the easiest way to have 2 networks. I'm thinking maybe two routers one subnetting off the other or a special VLAN switch?
I am not very technical and just want a simple cost effective solution,

Comment: Can be done with two cheap home routers, but you need to know quite a bit about networking and installing Open Firmware etc., so it's probably not an option. I don't know any non-technical "it just works" pre-made solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make two different networks in one intranetwork. For example, R1 assign for 192.168.1.1 /24 and R2 assign for 192.168.2.1 /24 (those are default gateways). Then a chosen router for netflix assign for certain DHCP pool as you would like to. After that, remove DHCP from the router for your own usage and assign IP addresses manually (specify the default gateway of the chosen router with no DHCP accordingly). 
No one won't be able to reach the separated networks coexisting in one. Don't forget to connect routers' LAN interfaces together to provide the channel for both networks.
I  hope it will be suitable for you, sir

Comment: This won't provide real security, because the only "secret" is the non-DHCP subnet address. It can be sniffed on the network.

Answer (score 1):

There’s only one ideal solution: Your router must create multiple separate networks. Not typically a feature found in SOHO routers. Still, there are some that can create a wired guest network, which would be perfect for you.

A “proper router” also does not have to be expensive. Depending on your expertise and performance requirements, you could go for a router that can be used with OpenWrt or a Mikrotik router. The basic idea is:

- Have two LAN networks (normal, with DHCP and the like)
- Each LAN network is bound to one (or more) physical ports on the router
- The LAN networks cannot talk to each other (firewall rules on the router)

---

If you don’t want to spend any money and you have two routers lying around, you can also go for double NAT. Depending on your port forwarding needs, this will create non-trivial management overhead though.

- Two routers, “outer” (guest network) and “inner” (private network)
- Inner router’s WAN port is connected to one of outer router’s LAN ports
- All private stuff is connected only to inner router
- All guest stuff is connected only to outer router